# Getting the value of a cell from its relative position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've recently been asked to create a spreadsheet for work that will return the lowest bid price from any of our suppliers. I got the basic spreadsheet from management and they want me to get it working. It looks like this

[image: Spreadsheet example]

I've found the minimum value from the four pricing columns easily enough, but I need to get the vendor id and the deal number and display them on the right side as well, as this spreadsheet could have tens of thousands of entries.

Does anyone know of any method I could use to get the Vendor ID and Deal Number values from their relative position to the smallest price value?

Comment: Use Match() to find the position of the bid number, then work from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the lowest price vendor.

=INDEX(B2:Q2,MATCH(R2,B2:Q2,0)-3)

Since Vendor appears three columns to the left of price, you are offsetting match by -3. For bid number you will offset by -2.

However, there is more than one vendor with the lowest price, you will get the one who appears first.